# How to connect to an headless service in Kubernetes from outside?

Tags: kubernetes, ip, cluster-computing, endpoint, internals

I created an headless service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-service-headless
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
  selector:
    app: myapp
  clusterIP: None
```

From Kubernetes dashboard I can see its `Internal endpoints`:

```
myapp-service-headless:80 TCP
myapp-service-headless:0 TCP
```

In this application, I also set internal endpoint to:

```
http://myapp-service-headless
```

But from outside, how can I access its IP to connect API?

For example, my Kubernetes' IP is `192.168.99.100`, then connect to `192.168.99.100` is okay?

## Now the service status from Kubernetes dashboard

### Services

[image]

### Service Details

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is two option to expose the service outside, you can use the ingress controller to connect to the server.

The simple method is change your service type to NodePort, then you should be able access server using NodeIP and service external port number.

here is the more info.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you see from my question, I didn't use `type` yet, but set `clusterIP` to `None`. So is it possible to add `type` and set to `NodePort ` now?

Comment: Yes, you can change it now. you can edit it in dashboard gui or use kubectl command `kubectl edit svc myapp-service-headless`